# CSS Lava Lamp Clip-path

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations, clip-path

So I am trying to make a "clip-path lava lamp" effect. my body has an animated gradient and a section with a white background. in the section is a lava effect. the lava is red right now but I'm trying to make it a clip-path on the section white background so I can see through the white background of the section and see the body gradient. I don't want to add the gradient to the lava because the animation doesn't line up and it looks bad. is this possible?

```
<section class="content">
<div class="lamp">
    <div class="lava">
      <div class="blob"></div>
      <div class="blob"></div>
      <div class="blob"></div>
      <div class="blob"></div>
      <div class="blob"></div>
      <div class="blob"></div>
      <div class="blob"></div>
      <div class="blob"></div>
      <div class="blob top"></div>
      <div class="blob bottom"></div>
      
    </div>
</div>

<svg>
  <defs>
    <filter id="goo">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur" />
      <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 18 -7" result="goo" />
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>

<h1 class="">trying to make the red lava a clip-path. </h1>
<p class="">so i can see the gradient background behind the white section</p>
  
</section>
```

```
body {
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #E26373, #0098C3, #359F68);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  height:100vh;
}
section.content {
  position: relative;
 height:80vh
}
.lamp { background:white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  min-width: 100vw;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
}

.lava {
  filter: url("#goo");
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.blob {
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: red; 
}

.blob.top {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4%;
  top: -3%;
  left: 0;
}
.blob.bottom {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 110%;
  height: 4%;
  bottom: -3%;
  left: -50px;
}
.blob:nth-child(1) {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 35%;
  bottom: -15%;

  animation: wobble 4s ease-in-out alternate infinite,
    blob-one ease-in-out 13s infinite;
}
.blob:nth-child(2) {
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
  right: 24%;
  bottom: -65%;

  animation: wobble 5s ease-in-out alternate infinite,
    blob-two ease-in-out 22s infinite;
}
.blob:nth-child(3) {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  bottom: -15%;
  left: 34%;

  animation: wobble 6s ease-in-out alternate infinite,
    blob-three ease-in-out 16s infinite;
}
.blob:nth-child(4) {
  width: 135px;
  height: 135px;
  bottom: -19%;
  left: 30%;

  animation: wobble 7s ease-in-out alternate infinite,
    blob-four ease-in-out 12s infinite;
}
.blob:nth-child(4) {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  bottom: -19%;
  left: 30%;
  animation: wobble 8s ease-in-out alternate infinite,
    blob-four ease-in-out 12s infinite;
}
.blob:nth-child(5) {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  bottom: -25%;
  left: 34%;
  animation: wobble 9s ease-in-out alternate infinite,
    blob-five ease-in-out 32s infinite;
}
.blob:nth-child(6) {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  bottom: -25%;
  right: 34%;
  animation: wobble 10s ease-in-out alternate infinite,
    blob-six ease-in-out 12s infinite;
}
.blob:nth-child(7) {
  width: 235px;
  height: 35px;
  bottom: -85%;
  right: 40%;
  animation: wobble 11s ease-in-out alternate infinite,
    blob-seven ease-in-out 32s infinite;
}
@keyframes blob-one {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: translatey(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translatey(-700%);
  }
}

@keyframes blob-two {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: translatey(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translatey(-420%);
  }
}

@keyframes blob-three {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: translatey(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translatey(-305%);
  }
}
@keyframes blob-four {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: translatey(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translatey(-605%);
  }
}
@keyframes blob-five {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: translatey(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translatey(-700%);
  }
}
@keyframes blob-six {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: translatey(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translatey(-700%);
  }
}
@keyframes blob-seven {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: translatey(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translatey(-300%);
  }
}

@keyframes wobble {
  50% {
    border-radius: 42% 58% 70% 30% / 45% 45% 55% 55%;
  }
  100% {
    border-radius: 38% 52% 75% 36% / 50% 40% 50% 60%;
  }
}






.backGrade {
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #E26373, #0098C3, #359F68);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }

    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
    }

    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Haze32/7zvfxa4s/1/